Find all the images from the database that are present in this picture
I work with the interfaces of various programs on my computer, I find elements that I can interact with, for example buttons. At some point, I have accumulated a large number of buttons, and I need an optimal algorithm for finding them in this image.
I write in python, I tried cv2.matchTemplate - it just matches the template, and it seemed to me that this is not the optimal method, because I just have to go through the entire database, then I tried the methods of searching for key points: surf, sift, orb, their problem is that they do not always find key points for small buttons (and there are many of them in MS Word). I also tried to look for the contours of the images, and to match them, but I also could not come up with an optimal method.
The code example below cannot find the key points for the button.
enter image description here
enter image description here
img1 = cv2.imread( 'InputPhoto/6-2.jpg' , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 
img2 = cv2.imread( "InputPhoto/6-1.jpg" , cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE) 

sift = cv2.SIFT_create() 
keypoints1, descriptors1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1, None ) 
keypoints2, descriptors2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2, None ) 

bf = cv2.BFMatcher() 
matches = bf.knnMatch(descriptors1, descriptors2, k= 2) 

threshold = 0.55

good_matches = [] 
for m, n in matches: 
    if m.distance < threshold * n.distance: 
        good_matches.append(m) 

img_matches = cv2.drawMatches(img1, keypoints1, img2, keypoints2, good_matches, None , flags=cv2.DrawMatchesFlags_NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS) 

plt.figure(figsize = ( 20 , 10 )) 
plt.imshow(img_matches)


the right approach is to use system APIs that enumerate open windows, enumerate the widgets in the desired window, and then give you control over the widget's events. any vision approach is a bad idea. -- if you really wanted to approach this visually, i.e. with that template, matchTemplate is the "right" approach, feature matching is the wrong approach
